# Parse a negative prefix integer from string in java

Tags: java, int

Hi i have a string looking something like this 10 -1 30 -2 and i want to read the numbers between spaces. I can do this using a FOR statement and the code

```
Character.toString(myString.charAt(i));
```

and

```
Integer.parseInt(myString);
```

But i face a problem when i try to read negative number like -1 and i got the error message:

```
09-09 13:06:49.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3365): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '-' as integer
```

Any ideas how to solve this ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to parse a single *character* (`'-'`) (after converting it to a string, admittedly) instead of the string "-1". If you use `charAt` you'll be parsing a single *digit* at a time, so "10" will come out as 1 and then 0, not 10.

If you just split your string on spaces, you should be able to parse the strings with no problems.

Comment: This is not exactly what i was looking for but you gave me the general idea so i solved the problem :) thnx Jon :)

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you want?

```
for (String number : "10 -1 30 -2".split("\\s"))
{
    int x = Integer.parseInt(number);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

This will print:

```
10
-1
30
-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use a StringTokenizer to split the String at certain characters.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("10 -1 30 -2");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
  String intStr = st.nextToken();
  int x = Integer.parseInt(intStr);
  System.out.println(x);
}
```