# NumberFormatException: Invalid int "-"

Tags: java, android, xml

i have a problem. I have an EditText that has `android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"`. In Java code i have this

```
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int value = 0;
                String editContent = editText.getText().toString();
                if(editContent != null && editContent.length() > 0) {
                    value = Integer.parseInt(editContent);
                } 
                seekBar.setProgress(value);
            }
```

When i try to insert a negative number i have a NumberFormatException Invalid int "-". How can i solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse a negative prefix integer from string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360111/parse-a-negative-prefix-integer-from-string-in-java)

Comment: How will you setProgress a negative value?

Comment: Micro pravi i have a custom seek bar that accept negative number

Comment: it seems that you are trying to parse a single character ('-') as an integer. onTextChanged is called every time a character is typed in.

Comment: Yes, but i have no idea on how can i solve this problem. I read link posted by Saif but i don't understand how can i fix...

Comment: If you just split your string on spaces, you should be able to parse the strings with no problems.

Comment: May be you will get idea from this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360111/parse-a-negative-prefix-integer-from-string-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First time when you put "-", the method `onTextChanged` will be called, and parsing will be done on "-", that is not a valid int. 
So you need to escape parsing if string is "-".*

---

Use below code into `onTextChanged(...)`. ***Better is to move this code into `afterTextChanged(...)`***

```
int value = 0;
if (! TextUtils.isEmpty(arg0)) {
    String text = arg0.toString();
    if ("-".equals(text)) {
        // Nothing to do
    } else {
        value = Integer.parseInt(text);
    }
    seekBar.setProgress(value);
}
```

Comment: in your case `arg0`. The CharSequesnce variable which you get as parameter list of `onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, .... )`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the layout of the EditText:

```
android:digits="0123456789-."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   int value = 0;
   String editContent = editText.getText().toString();
   if(editContent != null && editContent.length() > 0 && !editContent.equals("-")) {
     value = Integer.parseInt(editContent);
   } 
     seekBar.setProgress(value);
  }
```

As onTextChanged is called after every character is typed in you try to parse the "-" character as an Integer, which results in an exception. With the modified code, you will set the value to 0 in these situations.

Comment: I need to accept also negative number and in this way i can't insert negative number.

Comment: Actually, you can. you just ignore the first input. That is why I have written that it will set the value to 0 (something you can easily change). But glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because integer cannot be parsed from `"-"` string.
You can add `try-catch` block:

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                int value = 0;
                String editContent = editText.getText().toString();
                if(editContent != null && editContent.length() > 0) {
                    value = Integer.parseInt(editContent);
                } 
                seekBar.setProgress(value);
            }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            }
        }
```

or use `if` construction:

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int value = 0;
            String editContent = editText.getText().toString();

            if(editContent != null && !editContent.equals("-")){
                if(editContent != null && editContent.length() > 0) {
                    value = Integer.parseInt(editContent);
                } 
                seekBar.setProgress(value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to see if the editContent starts with -

```
@Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int value = 0;
  String editContent = editText.getText().toString();

  if(editContent != null && editContent.length() > 0 && !editContent.startsWith("-")) 
  {
      value = Integer.parseInt(editContent);
  } 
  seekBar.setProgress(value);
 }
```