# Java : How do I check if any number(0 - 9) is present or not only after a minus(-) char in String?

Tags: java, logic, operators

Let's assume I have a String `a`. I want to check if `a` contains numbers after minus sign. ex, `a="-78";`
If `a` has a number (here 7) only after minus sign(-) so that I can return `true` or `false` based on that.

Comment: Probably duplicate one did you search it before ask ?

Comment: Yes, I did but did not found appropriate question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a negative prefix integer from string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360111/parse-a-negative-prefix-integer-from-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
return a.matches("-\\d+");
```

Answer (score 0):

you may check the string with startsWith() method:

```
 String a =  0;
 a="-78";

 // Starts with
 boolean  b = string.startsWith("-7"); // return true
```

Answer (score 0):

> Let's assume if I have a String a. I want to check if a contains
>   numbers after minus sign. ex, a="-78";

```
boolean matches = s.matches(".*-\\d+");
```

With this you match with `a = "-78"` but also with  `a = "anything-78"`

Comment: Also, How do I do it with `a = "operator-78"`
Where, operator can be ` '+', '-', '*' or '/' `

Comment: This should do the job : `boolean matches = s.matches("[-+*/]-\\d+");`

Comment: Don't we need comma after every operator?

Comment: No, the syntax is like that. If you add  a comma as separator inside it, a comma char will be accepted during the matching :)  it is called a character class or character set. Look at this : http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple code like this:

```
String a = "-78";
int b = a.indexOf("-");
if(b == -1)
    //there is no "-".
else {
    int c = a.charAt(b+1);
    if(c >= 48 && c <= 57)
        // there is a "-" and after that you have a number.
}
```